# Multiple target directories in sbt project build

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sbt project in this structure:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── plugins.sbt
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── smcho
    │           └── App.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── smcho
                └── AppTest.java
```

With `sbt package`, I have three target directories, and target2 and target3 have a similar structure.

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── plugins.sbt
│   ├── project
│   │   └── target <---------- TARGET 1
│   └── target     <---------- TARGET 2
│       ├── config-classes
│       ├── resolution-cache
│       ├── scala-2.10
│       └── streams
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   └── test
│       └── java
└── target  <--------------- TARGET 3
    ├── resolution-cache
    │   ├── com.example
    │   └── reports
    ├── scala-2.11
    │   ├── classes
    │   └── hello_2.11-0.1.0.jar
    └── streams
        ├── $global
        └── compile
```

Why so? Interestingly, `sbt clean` does not remove the target directories, is there a way to have one simple target so that I can easily remove them?

This is build.sbt:

```
lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("An example task")
val junit = "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq( 
    organization := "com.example", 
    version := "0.1.0", 
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")). 
    settings(
        commonSettings: _*
). 
    settings(
        hello := { println("Hello!") },
        name := "hello",
        libraryDependencies += junit
)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every project in SBT has a `target` directory. That's where its compiled classes and other generated things go.

Your `root` is a project, and `TARGET 3` in your diagram is its target.

Your build definition (the `project` directory) is also a project. With SBT it is possible to write scala code to implement build-related tasks and settings. That compiled code has to go somewhere. It goes in the directory you labeled as `TARGET 2` - `project/target`.

Build definitions in SBT can be recursive, i.e. your build definition can have its own build definition. Since you are using plugins (defined in `project/plugins.sbt`), your build definition needs a build definition, which ends up being compiled to `project/project/target` aka `TARGET 1` in your diagram.

When you run `clean` in the SBT console, it will clean files from the current project's target directory. I don't think it's meant to delete the entire directory, but I could be wrong there. In any case, running `clean` while you have the `root` project selected should only affect the `root` project's `target`.

In the SBT console, you can run `reload plugins` or `reload return` to jump into and out of (respectively) the current project's build definition. Calling `clean` within that context would clean their respective `target`s.

As for combining them into a single, easily-removed directory, I'm not sure I see the value in that. Having used SBT for several years now, the various `target` dirs haven't ever really been in the way. I don't think I've even wanted to delete the target directory a single time in the last year or so.

Comment: And if you really want to wipe out absolutely all generated files everywhere, well, that's what `git clean` is for.